# how to document flask webapp

Tags: python, flask

I have to document a webapp I've developed with Python and the Flask framework. The documentation will contain the different features that the app offers to each role that may work with it.

I was thinking to include some wiki engine inside the app, because I need a easy way to improve the docs as the app evolves. What is the more natural way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You have many way to do it:

**Sphinx** (http://sphinx-doc.org/): The most used tool for python I think.

**PyDoc** (http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html): The old but native doc generator.

You talk about webapp, so If your app contains a **rest** API I suggest you using:

**Flask-swagger** (https://github.com/rantav/flask-restful-swagger): It will generate some part of the docs an let you define the rest

**apiDoc** (http://apidocjs.com/): Let you define all parts of your api in comments. You can customize the template etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Sphinx http://sphinx-doc.org.

I've used it on a couple of projects although I prefer to keep this sort of documentation separate from the code.